# Matplotlib - highlighting weekends on x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, axis-labels

I've a time series (typically energy usage) recorded over a range of days. Since usage tends to be different over the weekend I want to highlight the weekends.

I've done what seems sensible:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import random

#Create dummy data.

start=datetime.datetime(2022,10,22,0,0)
finish=datetime.datetime(2022,11,7,0,0)

def randomWalk(): 
    i=0
    while True: 
        i=i+random.random()-0.5
        yield i

s = pd.Series({i: next(randomWalk()) for i in pd.date_range(start, finish,freq='h')})

# Plot it.

plt.figure(figsize=[12, 8]);
s.plot();

# Color the labels according to the day of week.

for label, day in zip(plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='minor'), 
            pd.date_range(start,finish,freq='d')):
       label.set_color('red' if day.weekday() > 4 else 'black')
```

But what I get is wrong. Two weekends appear one off, and the third doesn't show at all.

[image: The X axis]

I've explored the 'label' objects, but their X coordinate is just an integer, and doesn't seem meaningful. Using DateFormatter just gives nonsense.

How would be best to fix this, please?

Comment: Although `date_range` has `both` value by default for its `inclusive` parameter, for some reason (that I could not figure out) the right side (as well as the weekend prior to that) are not included for your case: Nov.5 and 6 (weekend) and Nov. 7 (right side of range). If you put `print(day)` after `label.set_color('red' if day.weekday() > 4 else 'black')` you see what the loop iterates over. It does not seem to be an issue for the right side being one of T, W, T, or F though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that `xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='both')` is returning the labels in an evil order (minor ones first, then major ones); the major ones are the first, last and the first of the month. So really, to be able to set the color, we need to be able to do it from the label information. But at the moment, the labels I'm getting are just blank, which is bizarre. I can't find a way to work with the x value for a label.

Comment: It just seems mad. When I do:
`for label in plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='both'):
    print(label.get_position())` 
It just gives a row of (0, 0). Is there a way to force matplotlib to reformat the axes?

Answer (score 0):

OK - since matplotlib only provides the information we need to the Tick Label Formatter functions, that's what we have to use:

```
minorLabels=plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='minor')
majorLabels=plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='major')

def MinorFormatter(dateInMinutes, index):
    # Formatter: first param is value (date in minutes, would you believe), second is which item in order.
    day=pd.to_datetime(np.datetime64(int(dateInMinutes),'m'))
    minorLabels[index].set_color('red' if day.weekday()==6 else 'black') # Sunday
    return day.day

def MajorFormatter(dateInMinutes, index):
    day=pd.to_datetime(np.datetime64(int(dateInMinutes),'m'))
    majorLabels[index].set_color('red' if day.weekday()==6 else 'black') # Sunday
    return "" if (index==0 or index==len(majorLabels)-1) else day.strftime("%d\n%b\n%Y")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(MinorFormatter)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(MajorFormatter)
```

Pretty clunky, but it works. Could be fragile, though - anyone got a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib is meant for scientific use and although technically styling is possible, it's really hard and not worth the effort.

Consider using Plotly instead of Matplotlib as below:

```
#pip install plotly in terminal
import plotly.express as px
# read plotly express provided sample dataframe 
df = px.data.tips()
# create plotly figure with color_discrete_map property specifying color per day
fig = px.bar(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color='day', 
            color_discrete_map={"Sat": "orange", "Sun": "orange", "Thur": "blue", "Fri": "blue"}
            )
# send to browser
fig.show()
```

Solves your problem using a lot fewer lines. Only thing here is you need to make sure your data is in a Pandas DataFrame rather than Series with column names which you can pass into plotly.express.bar or scatter plot.

[image]